# How to fill missing observations in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a hypothetical time series data frame, which is with some missing observations (assumption is that the data frame shall include all dates and corresponding values and for all the dates in the year). As we can see in the head and tail information, there are certain dates and corresponding values are missing (30th Jan & 29th Dec). There would be many more such in the data frame, sometimes missing observations for more than one consecutive date.

Is there a way that missing dates are detected and inserted into the data frame and corresponding values are filled with a rolling average with one week window (this would naturally increase the number of rows of the data frame)? Appreciate inputs.

```
df.head(3)

    date        value
0   2020-01-28  25
1   2020-01-29  32
2   2020-01-31  45

df.tail(3)

    date        value
3   2020-12-28  24
4   2020-12-30  35
5   2020-12-31  37

df.dtypes
date     object
value     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `DaetimeIndex`, then use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) with rolling and `mean`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index('date').asfreq('d').rolling('7D').mean()
```

If need all values by year use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

idx = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
df = df.set_index('date').reindex(idx).rolling('7D').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael. This is what I want. But a query. Why does the resulting data frame is with 339 rows; shouldn't it be 366 rows? Any reason?

Comment: @Srinivas - hmmm, problem is not start first date by `2020-01-01`

Comment: I am very sorry :). Feeling ashamed. Thank you. :):)

Comment: @Srinivas - It is no problem, also added solution for all year data